# Twitter Bootstrap + SimpleForm: appending an icon to a form field doesn't show error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, validation, simple-form

I want to append an icon to a SimpleForm form field using Twitter Bootstrap. Here is the solution that I found in another SO question:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="birthday-picker" data-date="06-04-1986" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <%= f.input :birthday, :wrapper => :append do %>
        <%= f.input_field :birthday, as: :string, placeholder: "06-04-1986", readonly: true %>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

However, when I add this piece of code to my form, the validation kicks in but the message is not shown for that particular field. Any ideas on what's happening please?

### Update

Here is the HTML generated:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="birthday-picker" data-date="06-04-1986" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <div class="control-group date required error">
        <label class="date required control-label" for="user_birthday">Birthday <abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
        <div class="controls"><div class="input-append">
            <input class="string required readonly" id="user_birthday" name="user[birthday]" readonly="readonly" size="50" type="text" value="31-03-2012">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
        <span class="help-inline">You are too young</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the error message is generated. But for some reason, the span that contains the error message gets applied the following styles:

```
.input-append, .input-prepend {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Even though it's outside the `input-append` div... Any ideas what's happening?

### Update 2

The error message was in fact in an `input-append` div, which I removed. Now the error message appears but it's below the input, not inline like regular inputs...

Comment: you can disable `error` in <%= f.input :birthday, :error => false, :wrapper => :append do %> and render it with `f.error` wherever you want I guess.

Comment: If I do that, the error either doesn't appear or is not styled..

Comment: it's not styled even if you use it inside `input do` block?

Comment: if I put it into input do block it doesn't appear because it's generated inside an input-append div. If I don't mention f.error then the error is styled but appears below the input instead of inline like the other inputs.

Comment: but you always can override styles for you errors like `.help-inline { font-size: 10px !important; }` or something like that

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. But it seems hacky...

Comment: div class="input-append"> is your problem